# Disable Import errors table in Ms Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, importerror

Just to start with , I am not a very experienced programmer in Access. Is there any way I can disable the import error tables which are auto generated by access when you import files from excel ?

The reason I want to do this is my excel file has about 4000 rows with data about different locations,now the location I have to do the reporting on is importing properly thats why I am not worried about about the import errors . Also, it only detects the error in one row and because I import the table from vba code it will keep generating this error tables and I end up with big bunch of them.

I did some research but I find answer about solving the issue by fixing the file format of import , but I failed to get the answer about how to disable them.

Appreciate if anyone can help.

EDIT :

After suggestion from @parfait following code did the trick. Any other suggestions are also welcome.

`Sub dropImportError()
Dim tbl_name As DAO.TableDef, str As String
With CurrentDb
    For Each tbl_name In .TableDefs
            str = tbl_name.Name
            If InStr(str, "ImportErrors") <> 0 Then
            str = "DROP TABLE`" & str & "`"
            DoCmd.RunSQL str
            End If
    Next
End With
End Sub`

Comment: How are you importing? If using VBA with `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`, you can automate code that searches for error imports tables using tablesdefs and delete them after import? If using the wizard via the External Data tab on ribbon, in the last step uncheck the table analysis box.

Comment: @Parfait - Thank you for a prompt reply. So i assume there isn't any inbuilt option in Access to switch it off. I just wanted to know that. Also, thank you for you suggestion . The following code did the trick but I will appreciate if you can improvise the code if needed or else I will post it as answer. Thanks

Comment: Sub dropImportError()
Dim tbl_name As DAO.TableDef, str As String
With CurrentDb
    For Each tbl_name In .TableDefs
            str = tbl_name.Name
            If InStr(str, "ImportErrors") <> 0 Then
            str = "DROP TABLE `" & str & "`"
            DoCmd.RunSQL str
            End If
    Next
End With
End Sub

Answer (score 5):

```html
'Delete Import Error tables

Private Sub Delete_Error_Tables()
    Do Until IsNull(DLookup("Name", "Msysobjects", "Name like '*ImportErrors*'"))
        DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, DLookup("Name", "Msysobjects", "Name like '*ImportErrors*'")
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Just came across this issue myself, after running the import of procedure I immediately ran the following code which was saved in a stand-alone Module.  Simply paste the function `DeleteImportErrors` into the macro, procedure, or function.

Module code:

```
Public Function DeleteImportErrors()
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim db As DAO.Database

    Set db = CurrentDb
    For n = db.TableDefs.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    ' loop through all tables
        If InStr(1, db.TableDefs(n).Name, "ImportError") > 0 Then
        ' if table is import errors table
            DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, db.TableDefs(n).Name
            ' delete table
        End If
    Next n
End Function
```