# how to delete import error tables in access?

Tags: ms-access, module, vba

I am not a VBA expert. what I am trying to do is to import multiple csv files into access. access is creating bunch of import error tables after i import the files. i am using the code below to delete the error tables after i run a macro to import the csv files but it's not working. it's telling me user defined type not defined. any help is appreciated. I really appreciate if you can help me fix that code or find a different one

```
Sub dropImportError()

Dim tbl_name As DAO.TableDef, str As String
With CurrentDb
    For Each tbl_name In .TableDefs
        str = tbl_name.Name
        If InStr(str, "ImportErrors") <> 0 Then
            str = "DROP TABLE" & str & ""
            DoCmd.RunSQL str
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Well its seems youre so close to figuring this out on your own.... I would loop through all tables and debug.print; tbl_name.Name

Comment: (a) I think you need to put a space between the word `"TABLE"` and your table name - i.e. use `"DROP TABLE XYZABC"` rather than `"DROP TABLEXYZABC"`.  (b) Which line is giving the "user defined type not defined" error?

Comment: Thanks. this is the line where i am getting the message from:Dim tbl_name As DAO.TableDef

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Import errors table in Ms Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269502/disable-import-errors-table-in-ms-access)

Comment: Note that this `Dim tbl_name As DAO.TableDef` is invalid because you're using it in a for each loop, it should be `Dim tbl_name As Variant` since only variants are allowed there.

Comment: Thanks.I changed it to Variant. now i am getting errors saying syntax error in tables. and it highlighted DoCmd.RunSQL str after debug. i have bunch of tables with import errors, and can't name each table separate.

Comment: Did you make the change @YowE3K suggested?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth An object of the correct type can be used in a `For Each` loop.  (I tested the OP's code yesterday and it worked successfully for me [after adding the missing space after "TABLE"].)

Comment: @MikeF Check your references.  Your code works for me with the following references selected: `Visual Basic For Applications`, `Microsoft Access 15.0 Object Library`, `OLE Automation`, `Microsoft Office 15.0 Access database engine Object Library`.